Basic question about tensor Einstein notation
I thought I got the mechanics of Einstein summation, but I guess not, because I'm stuck reading page 24 of this paper.
It seems that the first expression expresses the entry $i$ of the vector resulting from the operation $\mathbf r = B \mathbf v$:
$$\mathbf r^i =\sum_{j=1}^D B_j^i \mathbf v^j = B^i_j \mathbf v^j$$
which could be pseud-coded as:
within a row i:
for columns j from 1 to D of the matrix B:
find the corresponding j entry in v and multiply
add all the products
return as r^i

This would make perfect sense.
However, in the following expression, which I think (?) is $\mathbf r =\mathbf v B $
$$\mathbf r^i =\sum_{j=1}^D B^j_i \mathbf v^j =\sum_{i=1}^D \mathbf v^j B^i_j =\mathbf v^j B^i_j$$
I have two questions:

The last expression seems identical to the one above, i.e. isn't $B^i_j \mathbf v^j == \mathbf v^j B^i_j$

given the the order of the elements (not the indices) is not relevant in Einstein's notation?

In the expression $\sum_{i=1}^D \mathbf v^j B^i_j$ what is the algorithm:

for rows of the matrix B from 1 to D:
what is j in B and what is j in v?


I think there is a typo in the paper. The equation you talk about is not about $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{v}B$, it is still talking about $\mathbf{r} = B\mathbf{v}$, and the authors want to show that in Einstein notation the order of symbols does not matter, only which indices are summed over. The equation should be
$$\mathbf{r}^i = \sum_{j = 1}^D B^i_j \mathbf{v}^j = \sum_{j = 1}^D \mathbf{v}^j B^i_j = \mathbf{v}^j B^i_j.$$
It is still $\mathbf{r} = B\mathbf{v}$. I think in terms of your pseudocode it would be something like
for entries j from 1 to D of the vector v:
for each row i of a matrix B:
find the corresponding j entry and multiply
add all the products
put into entry i of the output vector r

PS. If you use the convention that in a matrix $B^i_j$ the top index $i$ is the row number and the bottom index $j$ is the column number, then you also need to index your vectors accordingly. A column vector $v$ in the expression $Bv$ is indexed by row number, so it has a top index $v^j$ and the multiplication $Bv$ is indeed $B^i_j v^j$. But the row vector $v$ in the expression $vB$ is indexed by column number, so it must have the lower index $v_j$ and the multiplication $vB = \sum_{j = 1}^D v_j B^j_i$ is $v_j B^j_i$ (or $B^j_i v_j$, or $B^i_j v_i$) in Einstein notation.

This makes sense, and the OP is really a reality check for my understanding. However, I try not to be dismissive: the paper is really nice and clear, so giving the benefit of the doubt to the author, can you make sense of the question (2) in my OP?

I edited the answer
